# Strange error with ADO SQL string versus DoCmd.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to pass the following SQL string with ADO:

```
UPDATE ((JLE_Parcelas INNER JOIN ST_JLE_Municipios ON JLE_Parcelas.Cod_Parcelas_Municipio = ST_JLE_Municipios.Id_Municipios_Municipio) INNER JOIN ST_JLE_Provincias ON ST_JLE_Municipios.Cod_Municipios_Provincia = ST_JLE_Provincias.Id_Provincias_Provincia) INNER JOIN ST_JLE_Paises ON ST_JLE_Provincias.Cod_Provincias_Pais = ST_JLE_Paises.Id_Paises_Pais SET Parcelas_Alta_FechaFinal= NULL, Parcelas_Alta_FechaInicial= NULL, Parcelas_SIGPACNumPoligono= 20, Parcelas_SIGPACSuperficie= 79.9244, Parcelas_Observaciones='DDDDDEE', Parcelas_SIGPACNumParcela= 1, Parcelas_Contrato_FechaFinal= NULL, Cod_Parcelas_TipoProteccion= 1, Cod_Parcelas_TipoTenencia= 1, Cod_Parcelas_TipoRiego= 2, Cod_Parcelas_Agricultor= 4, Cod_Parcelas_Municipio= 195 WHERE Id_Parcelas_Parcela=7
```

but ADO returns Syntax error -2147217900 (systax error near '('.)

Notice I'm working with SQL Server database.

If I send the same string to Currentdb.execute, error dissapears and register is correctly saved, so I have two questions:

1. Can you tell me where is error in ADO?. I tried to find it, but it's impossible for me
2. is it better to use ado versus DoCmd, or vice versa?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With regards to the query, it looks fine so ADO's parser just must not like joining tables in an update query (something that I tried not to do anyway) . My experience is that in VBA, unless you are doing 1000+ writes to the db, there's no real performance hit to any of them. Generally I used DoCmd.RunSQL for simplicity, ADO for speed and CurrentDb.Execute for the good middle ground

Comment: Try using double-quotes instead of single-quotes  around the constant  parcelas_observaciones = 'DDDDDEE',   This is MS-Access, not SQLServer.